# Every user has different Login

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've Created one Application for login user and admin Every user will has different login with their details individually from login page. How it is?

```
    if (user == "Admin")
    {
        Response.Redirect("admin.aspx");
    }
    else if (user == "Employee")
    {
        Response.Redirect("employ.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.

Comment: what is your question? whether it is good or bad? that depends on number of such if else cases and future changes that may come.

Comment: @ManishMishra how will be authentication & authorization in this case? Its useful for this kind of purpose only?

Comment: Do you want the users, after they successfully logged in, to go to different pages depending on their role?

Comment: Thank you @ManishMishra just i want login, for example gmail type, in my gmail i can login nor others, like this i want funcationality for different users

Comment: return Response.Redirect("admin.aspx");

return Response.Redirect("employ.aspx");

Comment: Thank you Vond Ritz i asking about different employees, one company has so many employees every employee has individual login if i am logged to my account my page will displayed i cant see other account thats what i want

Comment: @Freelancer..see my answer, you need to get rid of RedirectFromLoginPage method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like, for different user role, you have different after successful login default screen.

simplest and most neat and scale-able thing you can do about it to store a default uri for each of the role in  your `RoleMaster` table (or watever you call it) i.e make your table like this:

```
   Id   RoleName    DefaultUri
    1    admin     ~/admin.aspx
    2    general   ~/home.aspx
```

now inside the login button click method do  this:

```
//User is any entity representing User Table data of yours.
User userObj = BALUser.GetUserByName(txtUserName.Text);
if(Authenticate(userObj)) //perform password comparison or forms authentication 
{
    Response.Redirect(userObj.Role.DefaultUri);
}
```

where `Authenticate`  is like:

```
public bool Authenticate(User user)
{
    //in case of forms authentication..
    return Membership.ValidateUser(user.UserName, user.Password);

    //or usual password comparison
    //return user.Password == txtPassword.Text.Trim();
}
```